# Generar código de producto laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel

Estuve intentando de varias formas el como generar un código de producto en laravel, el código debe ser generada por los campos de Categoría y SubCategoria. Ejemplo:

```
|Categoria |Sub_Categoria|Codigo |
|==========|=============|=======|
|Alimentos |Arroz        |ALAR001|
|Alimentos |Leche        |ALLE002|
```

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que usas `Eloquent`, podrías aprovecharte de los [eventos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events). Bastaría con escuchar el evento `saving`, así previo a que ocurra, reescribes tu campo:

```
Producto::saving(function($product) {
  $product->Codigo = "..."; //Logica de calculo de codigo
});
```

espero haberte ayudado. 
Saludos

Comment: También puede usar las bondades de los mutators para que el campo, cada vez que se guarde, se asigne el valor de acuerdo a la lógica que aplique en el mutator. Link de referencia: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators